# Transfer Vertex-Attributes to Texture bad texture results

Tags: textures, texture-mapping, vertex-attributes

I use MeshLAB 2022.02 on Windows 64 16GB RAM Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4790K CPU @ 4.00GHz 4.00 GHz

So currently I am working on creating a textured mesh from point cloud data. Firstly, I Compute the Normals for point sets; then Screened Poisson to create a mesh; then Parametrisation: Trivial Per-Triangle and lastly Transfer Vertex-Attributes to Texture.

It all seems to work flawlessly but my texture result is very bad, it doesn't appear smooth but rather triangulated. (Have attached screenshots below)

[Texture View 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HbCTU.jpg)

[Texture View 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AIZuK.jpg)

I have tried many different values for the px Dimensions but the result always seems the same.

I would really appreciate it if you can help me! Thank you!!!